# What is the best way to create a test automation suite as a service

Tags: java, web-services, selenium

I am trying to create the following setup :

1. A Selenium (Java) project that has a set of 10 automated test cases.
2. When this project is executed, it generates an HTML test execution report.
3. This project should be 'hosted' on an internal network.
4. Anyone who has access to the network should be able to 'invoke' this project, which in turn executes the test cases and passes the HTML report to the person who invoked it.
5. The project should be accessible ONLY for execution and the code should NOT be accessible.

My goal is that this implementation should be executable by any framework irrespective of the technology that the framework uses. I was thinking of creating the project as a WebService using Java (servlet).

My question is:

1. Can this implementation be accessed by any external automation framework ?
2. Are there any limitations to this implementation?
3. Is there a better way to implement this requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you write a Windows batch file (or equivalent) that kicks off the tests and takes an email as an input parameter? The final step would be to send an email to the provided address and attach the report.

Comment: Hey Jeff... The reason for this setup is a little more complex. I plan to integrate testing of two or more different systems. The results of one suite will have data that will be used by another. So I want the reusable part of the test suite be available anytime by any framework on a given network.

Comment: I don't know your system but it's generally recommended to not have one test depend on another test let alone one suite depend on another suite. If suite1 fails due to bugs, etc. then suite 2 will likely fail due to bad data rather than due to actual bugs. I would suggest you look up some articles on best practices in automation and test independence.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a maven project and have your automated tests under maven test folder.Configure your tests to run through POM.xml(use maven surefire plugin).Configure a jenkins job to run the maven test.Anybody with access the jenkins can build/run this task!

Below link should give you a headstart
http://learn-automation.com/selenium-integration-with-jenkins/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I plan to use this test suite as a subset in a larger part of testing. This will be used for integration testing of multiple systems. The result of this suite will provide data to another set of test cases.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, it is something we did on one of our projects. As I cannot share specifics, I will give you overall architectural view of the project.

The core of all things was a service that could run JUnit tests on requests. It was a Soap web-service, but nothing stops you from making it REST. To implement this you need to implement your version of JUnit test runners (see for example: http://www.mscharhag.com/java/understanding-junits-runner-architecture or https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-runners)

If you use JUnit as test framework for running your Selenuim tests this may be a great solution for you - JUnit will generate HTML reports for you if you configure it properly, it will hide actual test suite implementation from users and run test suite on demand. This solution is also great because it operates on JUnit level and does not care about what kind of tests it actually runs, so it can be also reused for any other kind of automated tests.

So to answer all your questions:

Can this implementation be accessed by any external automation
    framework ? -> yes, it can be accessed by anybody who able send http
    requests

Are there any limitations to this implementation? -> none that I am
    aware of

Is there a better way to implement this requirement? -> well, I
    didn't actually work with TestNG much so I don't know if it is
    easier or more difficult to do it on Junit level. You can use
    Jenkins or other CI tool as well to achieve same results - they can
    run JUnit tests for you and almost always have API ready for this,
    although those APIs may be not perfect.

So I'd say that if you need this only for one thing you can use CI tools for this purpose, if you don't have CI tools available then choice has been made for you. However, from our experience, having this kind of service was a great asset for a company and I really wonder why there's no such products available elsewhere yet.